# Python foreach not looping properly

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, sqlite

I'm writing a script that formats a bunch of csv files into one csv file.

To do this, I'm using a couple of cursor tables in python via sqlite.

Here is my code - currently I'm just trying to get every row in gsap that is associated with a code that is in gsap_locs to print

```
data = c.execute("SELECT * from gsap_locs")
for row in data:
    print row[0]
    d2 = c.execute("select date, cardtype, volume, transactions from gsap where gsaploc=?", (row[0],))
    for r2 in d2:
        print r2
```

However, my code is only returning one row.  I know that the problem isn't in the first `for` because when I take out everything after `print row[0]` it prints out all of the values from the first select.

Why is it escaping out of my first for after my second for runs without satisfying the conditions of the first for?

Comment: R2D2 lol... did you ask C3P0 for help?

Comment: that was a happy coincidence - I realized I had written it in there and thought "Well, this is definitely going to remain in the code because it has to now."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `fetchall` or `fetchone` instructions.
It's a common thing, we think that the `execute` has done the job of getting the data but you should use `fetch`.
To retrieve data after executing a SELECT statement, you can either treat the cursor as an iterator, call the cursor’s fetchone() method to retrieve a single matching row, or call fetchall() to get a list of the matching rows.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('gasp.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM gsap_locs")
rows = c.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row[0]
    c.execute("select * from gsap where loc=?", (row[0],))
    d2 = c.fetchall()
    for r2 in d2:
        print r2
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `cursor.execute` can only track one operation/returns an iterator at a time. You might want to keep the results of the first operation in memory, calling `tuple` on it:

```
data = tuple(c.execute("SELECT * from gsap_locs")) 
for row in data:
   ...
```

Be sure to have enough memory to hold all the results from the first query.